# can a PHP array return a function?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that shuffles through a few numbers. As you can see from my code I want to store it in an array. Is there a way to do this and on calling that array have it output separated by commas? I can get `print_r` to output the code but its not the way i want it.

```
function random($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max); 
    shuffle($numbers); 
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
$box=array(random(0,5,6));
```

Comment: The question header seems off somehow. Also, I am sorry but this looks like homework. At least it does not show much research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `implode()` function for convert array to comma separated string.

```
function random($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max); 
    shuffle($numbers); 
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
$box=random(0,5,6);
print_r($box);
$box1 = implode(",",$box);
echo "<br> Comma Seperated String : ".$box1;
```

**output**

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 [5] => 0 ) 
Comma Seperated String : 4,5,3,2,1,0
```

**Check in Editor: [Click Here](https://eval.in/554053)**

Comment: glad to help you. :)